# Problem when running Nuxt 3 app: Cannot find package node_modules\.pnpm\nuxt@3.2.3_sass@1.58.3\node_modules\nuxt\node_modules\estree-walker\

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, pnpm

So im just making a nuxt 3 project when this error pops up when i run: pnpm run dev:

```
Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find package 'C:\Users\Khaniya Family\vue\node_modules\.pnpm\nuxt@3.2.3_sass@1.58.3\node_modules\nuxt\node_modules\estree-walker\' imported from C:\Users\Khaniya Family\vue\node_modules\.pnpm\nuxt@3.2.3_sass@1.58.3\node_modules\nuxt\dist\index.mjs

  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
  at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:202:9) 
  at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:781:14)   
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:843:20)    
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1058:11)  
  at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)       
  at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:837:30) 
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:418:18)
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)
```

I tried to run pnpm install but it came up with the same error I tried to use yarn and npm but they also said the same exact thing Help!!!!

nuxt.config.ts:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    ],
    css: [
        "vuetify/styles/main.sass",
        "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: ["vuetify"]
    },
})
```